# Trying to retrieve VideoMediaMetaData of a video file in google drive

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api

I am trying to retrieve metadata of a video file present in my google drive. I can access all the information related to that file (like size, mimetype, etc.). But, when I am trying to retrieve metadata of that video file I am getting a null value. Could you please tell me how can I retrieve metadata of a video file. Thanks in advance.

```
VideoMediaMetadata video_Media_MetaData=file.getVideoMediaMetadata();
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, a successful HTTP request using [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list) will return a response body which includes `videoMediaMetadata` in the following structure:

```
{
  "kind": "drive#fileList",
  "nextPageToken": string,
  "incompleteSearch": boolean,
  "files": [
    "videoMediaMetadata": {
       "width": integer,
       "height": integer,
       "durationMillis": long
    },
    "isAppAuthorized": boolean
  ]
}
```

However, please note that, as described in [Files documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#resource), `videoMediaMetadata` is

> Additional metadata about video media. This may not be available immediately upon upload.

Thus, it will return `null` for none as mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/drive/model/File.html#getVideoMediaMetadata()).

With this, you may want to try [Files: update](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/update) to update a file's metadata and/or content with patch semantics.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. I figured it out. I need to set the field videoMediaMetadata before executing the list(), then the response body would include the metadata of the video file. If possible could you please look into this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45801256/how-to-partially-download-google-drive-files

Comment: @HeenShaik Could you please give more details about "set the field videoMediaMetadata before executing the list()"? Do you do that with update() or something like this?